# Inputstick : AES-128 encryption (CBC mode) over Bluetooth connection

Tags: password-management, aes, hardware

There is *"Inputstick"* device offering way to transport passwords to computer over USB wireless via: 
AES-128 encryption (CBC mode) over Bluetooth connection
http://inputstick.com/index.php/en/about-en/security-en

Assuming it's used to transport credentials (e.g. through [KeePass2Android Offline](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=keepass2android.keepass2android_nonet&hl=en) on Android with [KP2APlugin plugin](https://github.com/inputstick/KP2APlugin) (and [more about it](http://inputstick.com/index.php/en/applications-en/kp2a-plugin-en) ) , how would you asses security of proposed solution and used cryptographic algorithms?
(not asking about assesment of used Android hardware: you may assume device is freshly patched, offline with only Bluetooth turned on and only Inputstick paired).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would check is what is the entropy source in this device. There is no such thing as strong cryptography without a good entropy source (and also usually a good CPRNG).

Then you need to check how keys and IVs are generated and handled. Keys need to be securely transmitted or negotiated (using something like Diffie-Hellman) this in turn requires authentication to defend against active attackers (MITM). How does the device knows it talks to a legitimate user and not an attacker?